# JSON Data does not match and usage of track by, as

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have three select menus that connected to each other.

-First one display: Series names

-Second one display: Chapter numbers that belongs to series that in the first select menu.

-Third one display: Page numbers that belongs to chapter that in the second select menu.

Now what i want is set selected values for first and second select menus according to `$scope.data`. In my controller I manage to set first one but second one didn't work because of JSON data does not match. If I use `track by` its working but this time I cant use `as`. How can i solve this?

```
<select ng-model="selManga" ng-options="manga.seri for manga in mangalar track by manga.seri"> 
<option value="">Manga</option> 
</select>
<select ng-change="selPage = 0" ng-model="selChapter" ng-options="selManga.randomword.indexOf(chapter) as chapter.klasor for chapter in selManga.randomword"> 
<option value="">Chapter</option> 
</select>
 <select ng-model="selPage" ng-options="selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol.indexOf(page) as selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol.indexOf(page) + 1 for page in selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol">
</select>
<img ng-src="{{selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol[selPage]}}" ng-click="next(selManga, selChapter, selPage)">
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.mangalar = loHemen; //JSON Data
$scope.selManga = miloMangaInArray; // First select menu's ng-model and its working.
$scope.selChapter = $scope.selManga.randomword[a]; //Second select menu's ng-model and its not working due to no matching JSON data.
```

JSON Data:

```
[{"seri": "Naruto",
  "randomword": [{
        "klasor": "138",
        "yol": [path/to/images
    ]
},
{
        "klasor": "300",
        "yol": [path/to/images

    ]
}
]
},
{
 "seri": "One Piece",
 "randomword": [
{
        "klasor": "137",
        "yol": [path/to/images

    ]
}
]
}
])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Json Data is not valid;

Valid example is:

```
[{"seri":"Naruto","randomword":[{"klasor":"138","yol":["a","b","c"]},{"klasor":"300","yol":["a","b","c"]}]},{"seri":"Naruto","randomword":[{"klasor":"139","yol":["a","b","c"]},{"klasor":"301","yol":["a","b","c"]}]}]
```